# Select unique rows with same value of a column Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to select rows with unique values from a table with user column and a,b and c columns having duplicate rows on the same user. PS: Rows with different users and same values for a,b and c should stay. But rows with the same user and same values should be ignored.
Example before transformation :

```
+-------+-----------------+--------+------+
| User  |        a        |   b    |  c   |
+-------+-----------------+--------+------+
| user1 | False           | active | 10.0 |
| user1 | False           | active | 10.0 |
| user2 | False           | active | 10.0 |
| user2 | True            | active | 10.0 |
+-------+-----------------+--------+------+
```

After the transformation:

```
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| User  |   a   |   b    |  c   |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
| user1 | False | active | 10.0 |
| user2 | False | active | 10.0 |
| user2 | True  | active | 10.0 |
+-------+-------+--------+------+
```

So for a unique user we should not have duplicate rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include some sample data as well as what you have tried so far that hasn't worked. For the best chance at getting good answers, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `distinct`?

```
select distinct user, a, b, c from mytable
```

Comment: Same user can have multiple rows with different values on the other columns

Comment: @AhmedMasmoudi: you might need to provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: I already did update the description, I hope you can help

Comment: @AhmedMasmoudi: the above query would produce the desired results for your sample data.